# Change/Toggle Link(href) after click

Tags: hyperlink, toggle, href

i need a solution for this problem:

I have two links:
**Link A:** www.example.com/?number=123
**Link B:** www.example.com/?number=456

On the website should be **ONE** clickable link. This link should automatically change/toggle between my two links after a user clicked on it. (So a user clickes on the link and gets to site **A**, and on the next click the user gets to site **B**, then to **A**.....and so on)

I searched this site and the web but i can´t find a solution for my exact problem...in addition i am no programmer. (The website is running wordpress 4.0.1, if this is relevant)

Thx for your help!

Comment: Is this a link that opens in a new window/tab?

Comment: The link opens in new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

This a little bit hacky, but the following javascript does what you want:

```
function toggleLink() {
    // Rebind this for the closures below
    var self = this;

    // Edit the following two links as needed
    var link1 = 'http://www.example.com/?number=123';
    var link2 = 'http://www.example.com/?number=456';

    // The event triggers before the page is opened, so href needs to be amended at a later point.
    // I have arbitrarily chosen 100ms after the click event.
    if (this.href === link1) {
        setTimeout(function () { self.href = link2; }, 100);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () { self.href = link1; }, 100);
    }
}

document.getElementById('toggle-link').addEventListener('click', toggleLink);
```

See the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uphbs9vu/1/)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the fast response and the code! But i think i need something different. (Sorry if i was not clear enough about it) With this code, the link is changing just for the user. I need the link to be changed on the website for all users! So user A clicks the link A and it changes; and when user B is clicking the link, the link has changed to link B...

Comment: In which case, you'll need some server-side code and a database to store the state.